# Perimeter points in triangle

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ denotes a triangle and $p(ABC)$ denotes its perimeter. We say two points $O_1$ and $O_2$ inside this triangle are perimeter points if there are points $a$, $b$ and $c$ on the sides $BC$, $AC$ and $AB$ respectively, such that we have $$p(BO_1a)+p(aO_2C)=p(ABC),$$
$$p(CO_1b)+p(bO_2A)=p(ABC),$$
$$p(AO_1c)+p(cO_2B)=p(ABC).$$

My question is:

Is it true that each triangle has perimeter points?

$\textbf{Added later}:$

If we relax the problem and just the below condition be true, does this problem have a solution?

$$p(BO_1a)+p(aO_2C)=p(ABC).$$

Comment: I think obtuse angled triangle would be a counterexample

Comment: Have you tried $O_1=O_2$ be one of the triangle centers? Also, do you require $a$ between $B$ and $C$ or just on the line they determine? SInce the conditions on $a,b$ and $c$ are independent you should usually be able to perturb two perimeter points and get another pair.

Comment: But if $O_1=O_2$, we have one triangle inside the original triangle (on the fixed edge say $AB$) and the perimeter is less than the original one. The point, say $a$, must be between $B$ and $C$.